# Copy Oracle table from one database to other database without DBLink

Tags: database, oracle, sql-loader

I need to copy table from one oracle database to another oracle database. I am using SQLLDR for the same as I don't have DB links.

As the table size is very huge (around 160 GB), the extracting data in flat file takes around 4-5 hrs, I am also facing storge issue at unix box, and loading through sqlldr is also taking much of time.

Can anyone please help me on the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Oracle 10G (or above) you can leverage Oracle Data Pump utility which will allow you to export/import databases with compression on the fly. Depending on the Oracle Database version, you can have a look at the official Oracle documentation that contains examples of how you can do DB export/import operations.

Comment: Thanks. But I dont have privileges to Create Directory in SQL Plus. Do you have any other option for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the data via sql, output or spool to a unix named pipe and immediately start another session with sqlldr loading from the named pipe ...

```
user@box> mkfifo my.fifo.pipe
user@box> sqlplus -s user/pwd@sourceservice @script-spooling-to-my.fifo.pipe

<ANOTHER UNIX SESSION>
user@box> sqlldr userid=user/pwd@destinationservice control=.... data=my.fifo.pipe
```

Comment: Here's someone doing it with compression as well! http://www.simonecampora.com/blog/2010/07/09/how-to-extract-and-load-a-whole-table-in-oracle-using-sqlplus-sqlldr-named-pipes-and-zipped-dumps-on-unix/

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use DBLinks and can't use datapump, you can use an ETL tool, Pentaho Data Integration for example or other, as a simple option.